# make a program return True if there is more than one dot in the string?

Tags: python

so I'm new to programming (and python) and I have to make this program that returns True if the string has zero or one dot characters ("." characters) and return False if the string contains two or more dots

here is what I currently have, I cannot get it to work for me, please correct me if I am wrong, thanks!

```
def check_dots(text):
text = []

for char in text: 
    if '.' < 2 in text:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: The title says to return False, the text says to return True.

Comment: a lot of mistakes here: (1) text should not be set to an empty list at the start of the function.  that causes you to be searching an empty list for '.'.  (2) your code needs to be indented underneath the function definition line.  (3) `if '.' < 2 in text:` is not a valid line of Python code.

Comment: ^this comment should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the builtin Python function [`list.count()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_count.htm)

```
if text.count('.') < 2:
    return True
```

It can be even shorter if instead of an `if-else` statement, you do

```
return text.count('.') < 2
```

Also, there are some errors in your function. All you need to do is

```
def check_dots(text):
    return text.count('.') < 2
```

Comment: it keeps returning "None" for me? I don't understand why

Comment: @Dom It's because of the list you are using. Check the snippet I added at the end of my answer

Comment: thanks so much! I spent so much time on this and it was just a simple fix

Comment: @michaelpri :O lmao take a screenshot

Comment: @Player72 Done. devil.png. Hehe

Comment: @michaelpri omg it's not 695 you're no longer the devil. not_devil.jpg

Comment: @Player72 :( it was a good day being the devil, but I must pass the stick on to someone else ;)

Comment: @Player72 One of [these guys](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31?sort=reputationchange&page=2106) can take over :)

Answer (score 1):

A correct and shorter version would be:

```
return text.count('.') <= 1
```

Comment: it returned "None" for me? I'm confused

Comment: @Dom check our input, the text should be a _string_, not a list. Remove the line with `text = []`.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a function called [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

You can do the following.

```
if text.count('.') < 2: #it checks for the number of '.' occuring in your string
    return True
else:
    return False
```

A shortcut would be:

```
return text.count('.')<2
```

Let's analyze the above statement.
in this part, `text.count('.')<2`: It basically says "I will check for periods that occur less than twice in the string and return True or False depending on the number of occurences." So if text.count('.') was 3, then that would be `3<2` which would become `False`.

another example. Say you want it to return `False` if a string is longer than 7 characters.

```
x = input("Enter a string.")
return len(x)>7
```

The code snippet `len(x)>7` means that the program checks for the length of `x`. Let's pretend the string length is 9. In this case, `len(x)` would evaluate to 9, then it would evaluate to `9>7`, which is True.

Answer (score 0):

I shall now analyze your code.

```
def check_dots(text):
text = [] ################ Don't do this. This makes it a list, 
                         # and the thing that you are trying to 
                         # do involves strings, not lists. Remove it.

for char in text: #not needed, delete
    if '.' < 2 in text: #I see your thinking, but you can use the count()
                        #to do this. so -> if text.count('.')<2:  <- That
                        # will do the same thing as you attempted.
        return True
    else:
        return False
```